# iPhone short file to play

Tags: iphone, audio, ios6, avqueueplayer

I am wondering if it is possible to play several little audio files on iPhone. I created a sound file of 25µs but I can't play it on Simulator or on the Device.
So I created several files 25µs, 50µs and 100µs but even if I use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` with ÀVQueuePlayer`I couldn't play it!

Do someone know the minimum time to play a sound or if what I am doing is possible?

Thank you for your answers

PS : My project is to communicate with other device on the audio

Comment: There are so many things that are not said here, it's hard to know where to begin.  For a start,  what is the sample rate? what are the signals you attempting to play? define what 'audible means' in this context.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it is not being played ?  25µs is 25 millionth of a second long !
I suggest you start playing a clip which is audible, then cut its length in half
and repeat until it becomes inaudible.  Is your intention to have the other device listen ? you could get your play/listen loop working with audible clips then drill down.